# How do I navigate between existing UIViewControllers from a "menu" view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a menu view controller with buttons that should take me to a different view controller. I do not have a navigation controller in my storyboard. Currently I transition to new view controllers using segues, both through storyboard as well as programatically. My menu view controller is presented modally when it is called. How can I navigate to a already instantiated view controller instead of making new ones every time?

Comment: for that you have to save reference of already created view controller gloabally may be in AppDelegate, then when you present it again from menu use that reference..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **Unwind** segue.

I assume there are three ViewControllers A(Menu),B and C.
Now you press button on A and you moved to B,
Now you press button on B and moved to C.

**Now you wants to come back to ViewController A,**

**Step 1:** Create this function on ViewController A.

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewControllerA(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
    //do your stuff here.
}
```

**Step 2:** Suppose you have button on **ViewController C**,after clicking on that you wants to come back to **ViewController A**.

-So go to **ViewController C** in StoryBoard,
-Ctrl+drag from "Go to A View Controller" button to Orange Exit button as shown in image,

[image]

-And click on unWindToViewControllerA.

That's it.

Now after clicking on button "Go to A View Controller" you will go to "ViewController A."

I also recommend to read this [Technical note from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html).

Comment: I was trying to use an unwind function, and even made a manual segue with an identifier by drag from that yellow icon to the exit icon. But the problem is that the menu can be called from any view controller.

Currently this is my setup: I have two view controllers and a menu view controller. The first view controller (A) has a button that segues to (B) and both (A) and (B) have a button to the menu view controller (C). I have a function that determines if the view controller that presented the menu is the view controller that the button you pressed on the menu is trying to go to which works.

Comment: Yes, so in any of your view controller create a button, then follow the `Step:2`.
That will `unWind` to View Controller A.

Comment: I'm not getting you,Is your Menu View Controller is Initial View Controller in StoryBoard.?

Comment: Initial view controller is A, segues to B, I open up C and click the button that should take me back to A. Using a manual unwind segue, it does take me back to A but then when I try to use the menu button again it complains 

Warning: Attempt to present <LADM.MenuViewController: 0x155d3feb0>  on <LADM.ToursAndCitiesViewController: 0x155d0f5f0> which is already presenting <LADM.CompOrderViewController: 0x15680aa00>

And none of the transitions work any more.

Comment: Are you writing some thing in method shown in `Step:1`?

Comment: What should I be putting in there?

Comment: I'm just asking if you are putting something there.

Comment: No currently nothing is there.